# JavaScript show more on target button

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, addeventlistener

I am trying to add a "show more/show less" button for articles on my blog.

Issue 1. I have been able to get the event to work but because it wasn't targeting the clicked button, the event opened and closed all content together.

Issue 2. I got it to open and close on the target, but now other buttons that should have a similar action won't do any thing.

Here is the snippet of the code so far, thanks in advance.

```js
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let myTarget = e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON';
  if (myTarget && content.className == 'content open') {
      //shrink the box
      content.classList.remove("open");
      this.innerHTML = "Show More";
  } else {
      //expand the box
      content.classList.add("open");
      this.innerHTML = "Show Less";
  }
});
```

```css
.show-more {
    background: #1594e5;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans- 
serif;
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content p {
    width: 600px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 10;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans- 
serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #444;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Set transitions up. */
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.7s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.7s;
    transition: max-height 0.7s;
}

.content.open p {
    width: 600px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 10;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans- 
serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #444;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Set transitions up.*/
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.7s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.7s;
    transition: max-height 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <h2>Welcome to my <span class="primary-text">Blog</span></h2>
    <h1>Apr 2, 2018 blog post</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
Tempore maxime fugiat itaque nesciunt alias iure enim quasi quae in 
voluptatum, aliquid debitis ad excepturi, illo velit aperiam cum. A, 
possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
    <button class="show-more">Read More</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went off on a different tangent, to see if this would help...

Instead of an Event Listener, I added the function call to the button's onclick:

```
<button class="show-more" onclick="contentView(this);" data-state="closed">Read More</button>
```

I also gave it a data-* element, named data-state.

The idea is that by calling directly from the button you don't have to worry about checking where the action was triggered from.
Additionally, by setting the data-state on the button, we can track the open/closed value of the button without diving into CSS class names (or trying to keep track of it in the JavaScript itself).  It's just a nice way to track data of an element without going into a lot of digging through it's attributes.

The button's onclick passes the term `this` which lets us target the element calling for the action... (which inside the function the button is represented by the parameter name 'element')

The function looks a little like this:

```
function contentView( element ){
    let parent = element.parentNode;
    let content = parent.querySelector('.content');
    let state  = element.getAttribute('data-state');
    if( state.toLowerCase() === 'closed' ){
        element.setAttribute('data-state', 'open');
        element.innerHTML = 'Show Less';
        content.classList.add('open');
    }else{
        element.setAttribute('data-state', 'closed');
        element.innerHTML = 'Show More';
        content.classList.remove('open');
    }
}
```

Here's a link to the JS fiddle I made using your original code.
https://jsfiddle.net/tqx5yfco/45/

(the jsFiddle demo in action)
https://fiddle.jshell.net/tqx5yfco/45/show/

I added in duplicate sections to show the code in effect with different blocks.
(more comments can be found in the fiddle)

Comment: it's a valid approach, but almost everyone nowadays discourages the use of inline javascript functions (as putting `onclick` directly to an element) https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors on your JS, so it causes the problems.
First, I added `id` to the elements, so using vanilla JS you can easily find then in the DOM. 
**EDIT**
Ok, if you need many buttons working for different contents, then you need something similar to my edited code below. (it's not much consistent or very professional, but it works)

1. I moved the buttons inside the `divs`, so there's a way to know from which div each button belongs and works to.
2. Get all buttons on the page by `className`.
3. loop through each button adding the listener.
4. the listener is looking for the parent of the button and then for the `<p>` that is inside, this way you will find only one (if you keep this exact structure).
5. Check it out below.

(obs.: If you will have one `section` to every post, then you will need to modify my structure, but just follow this logic and you will get there)

```js
var allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("show-more");

for (var i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++){
  allButtons[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let myTarget = e.target;
    var content = myTarget.parentElement.children[0]; //get the first children = <p> 
    if (myTarget && content.style.display == 'block') {
        content.style.display = 'none'
        myTarget.innerHTML = "Show More";
    } else {
        //expand the box
        content.style.display = 'block'
        myTarget.innerHTML = "Show Less";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.show-more {
    background: #1594e5;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans- 
serif;
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content p {
    width: 600px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 10;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans- 
serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #444;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none; 
    /* Set transitions up. */
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.7s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.7s;
    transition: max-height 0.7s;
}

.open p {
    width: 600px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 10;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans- 
serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #444;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    /* Set transitions up.*/
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.7s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.7s;
    transition: max-height 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <h2>Welcome to my <span class="primary-text">Blog</span></h2>
    <h1>Apr 2, 2018 blog post</h1>    
    <div class="content" id="myContent">
        <p>News 1</p>
      <button class="show-more">Read More</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content" id="myContent">
        <p>News 2</p>
      <button class="show-more">Read More</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content" id="myContent">
        <p>News 3</p>
      <button class="show-more">Read More</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is a cool alternative. The only issue that I am having with this is that I can't use it to say, add another one. In my case I plan to have many posts on one page so I don't want them to all display, using this makes it so that I would have to give each button a separate ID and write new code. I am trying to use the target to be able to recycle the code without having to rewrite id's and new vars.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Never used this site myself (just read a lot of the solutions). I appreciate you taking the time to help.